# Find $L$ such that $L^*=LL$ but $L \neq LL$

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

I need example for a language that $L^*=LL$ but $L \neq LL$

I tried $L=\{w| |w| \text{ is even}\}$

but I cant find example

Comment: Could you provide more context and definitions?

Comment: I'm assuming $L^*$ is the Kleene closure of $L$. What is $LL$?

Comment: @R.Burton Yes...

Comment: I assume $LL$ is the Cartesian product of $L$ with $L$; e.g. if $L = \{"a", "b"\}$ then $LL = \{"aa", "ab", "ba", "bb"\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the set of all words over $\{a,b\}$ that are either empty or have a different number of $a$'s and $b$'s.  So $LL=L^*$ would be all words over $\{a,b\}$, but $L$ itself is not.

Or even simpler, $L=\{w\mid |w|\neq3\}$

Answer (score 1):

Take $L = 1 + a + a^3a^*$. Then $L^2 = L^* = a^*$, but $L \not= L^2$.